# Can I play Roblox on Xbox Silver (or free) on Xbox if I'm playing locally?

Tags: xbox-one, roblox

Can I play any Roblox games on my Xbox without a paid Xbox ( gold, etc) subscription?

Answer (score 3):

[Here](https://en.help.roblox.com/hc/en-us/articles/205091984-Xbox-One-App-How-to-Play-a-Roblox-Game#:%7E:text=An%20Xbox%20One%20console%20is,account%20and%20an%20Internet%20connection.&text=There%20are%20many%20different%20games,Home%20screen%20and%20Games%20screen.) and [here](https://www.quora.com/Do-you-need-Xbox-Live-Gold-to-play-Roblox) indicates that you can download Roblox on Xbox for free, however, to play online on Xbox you are required to have an Xbox Live Gold membership. You can play Roblox online for free on Mobile as well as PC.